# TFLite android Error - Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:2) with 131072 bytes to a Java Buffer with 2048 bytes

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I’m new to Android and TF and I’m having an issue that I couldn’t find any solution for. I have a model in python that I converted to TFLite and imported into Android Studio. When I imported it, here’s the sample code suggested for me by Android Studio:

```
val model = Model.newInstance(context)

// Creates inputs for reference.
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 64, 112, 112, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer
val outputFeature1 = outputs.outputFeature1AsTensorBuffer
val outputFeature2 = outputs.outputFeature2AsTensorBuffer

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
model.close()
```

I’m using the CameraX API to get the camera images and here is my analyze function:

```
override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {

    val bitmap = imageProxy.toBitmap()
    val scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 112, 112, true)
    scaledBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer)
    inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)
    val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
    imageProxy.close()
}
```

where byteBuffer and inputFeature0 are defined as members of my class like this:

```
val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1*64*112*112*3*4)
val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 64, 112, 112, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
```

When the model.process is called I’m getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:2) with 131072 bytes to a Java Buffer with 2048 bytes.
                                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.TensorImpl.throwIfDstShapeIsIncompatible(TensorImpl.java:444)
                                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.TensorImpl.copyTo(TensorImpl.java:216)
                                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:269)
                                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.InterpreterImpl.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(InterpreterImpl.java:101)
                                                                                                        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.model.Model.run(Model.java:274)
                                                                                                        at com.example.demo.ml.Model.process(Model.java:41)
                                                                                                        at com.example.demo.MainActivity$MyAnalyzer.analyze(MainActivity.kt:262)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis.lambda$setAnalyzer$2(ImageAnalysis.java:528)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysis$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.analyze(Unknown Source:2)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer.lambda$analyzeImage$0$androidx-camera-core-ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer(ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer.java:286)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.ImageAnalysisAbstractAnalyzer$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(Unknown Source:14)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

131072 is 64 times the value of 2048 and 64 is the number of frames my model expects. I tried to change the byteBuffer size to (112 * 112 * 3 * 4) but I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match. Expected: 9633792 Actual: 150528
```

which suggests that I had the size right before.

Any ideas?

Thanks